# Regarding communication between managed bean in JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

It seems I am not clear on my previous question about managed bean. So, I am posting it again in a more systematic manner.

I have one page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="head">

        </ui:insert>

        <br/><br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{MasterBean.laala}"/>
        <br/><br/>

        <ui:insert name="content">

        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is its bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="MasterBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MasterBean {

    private String laala;

    public String getLaala() {
        return laala;
    }

    public void setLaala(String laala) {
        this.laala = laala;
    }


    public MasterBean() {
    }

}
```

This is data.xhtml which uses master.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="master.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="head">
                laala
            </ui:define>

            <h:outputText value="#{pageBean.content}"/>

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:commandButton actionListener="#{pageBean.speakHello}"/>
            </ui:define>>


        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is its bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="pageBean")
@ViewScoped
public class pageBean {

    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public void speakHello(){
        //how do i get value of laaala here which is in MasterBean???
        content = ??? + " Hello friend";
    }

    public pageBean() {
    }

}
```

What should I put in the blank where `???` is marked in speakHello(). How do I get value of other bean in this bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can learn in a [JSF2 tutorial](http://mkblog.exadel.com/jsf/learning-jsf2-managed-beans/) one can use the dependency injection feature. In your case it would be about injecting `MasterBean` instance to `pageBean`. I believe you could have something like this in your `pageBean`:

```
@ManagedBean(name="pageBean")
@ViewScoped
public class pageBean {

    private String content;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{MasterBean}")
    private MasterBean masterBean;

    ...
```

a then use it in your methods:

```
 public void speakHello(){
    //how do i get value of laaala here which is in MasterBean???
    content = masterBean.getLaala() + " Hello friend";
 }
```

I haven't tried that myself. I hope it will work.

BTW, it's highly recommended not to start class name with a small letter. So `pageBean` class should be called `PageBean` instead.

Comment: Great! GrzegorzOledzki :). Vote and tick mark for correct answer. First, i got exception but fortunately it threw meaningful exception that getter and setters were not there. Once i created them, it's working smooth and fine. Wow thanks again :)

Comment: Also note that using ManagedBean is not "best practice". It is deprecated from JSF 2.3. You can use Named annotation instead and inject the MasterBean instance. If you are using JSF 2.0 or 2.1 it is fine because there is no native CDI view scope in those versions.