# Communication between two managed beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2 and Tomcat 7, and I have the following situation:

The users is on the Products CRUD screen, in the selected product he needs to specify the product brand.
So in this screen, I have a button that opens a new page (the Brand CRUD page), where the user can select the product brand and return the selected brand to the product, reopening the product page with the brand on the brand field.
How can I do this using JSF?

Comment: You wan to pass some value between the pages?

Comment: yes, i want to do a "conversation like" pattern, where yoou can open a new page, select the desired value, then return the selected value to the previous page.

Comment: I think a modal dialog suits you best. Primefaces has a modal dialog component. You can list your Brands in Modal dialog and select a brand from it. By using a modap dialog you do not need to navigate through pages so there will be no need for conversation scope. (PrimeFaces: http://primefaces.org/, ModalDialog: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.)

Comment: this is a good solution and its being used in some cases already, but in another cases we want to send the user to another page, so he can have full access to the functions that page have, eg.: create, update infos etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF question about communication between managed bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779480/jsf-question-about-communication-between-managed-bean)

Comment: Please tell the scope of managed bean with which you are working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup you can do this in many ways. Two of them are listed below:

1. Pass necessary data as a get parameter:

   ```
   <h:link value="Product" outcome="product">
       <f:param name="brand" value="#{bean.brand}"/>
   </h:link>
   ```
2. Use `flash` EL object to pass data between views:

   ```
   <h:inputText value="#{flash.brand}">
   ```

The rest depends on how you're going to use your data.