# Refactoring named beans to avoid code duplicity

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have detected I am repeating code in my named beans sistematically, so I am looking for a way to reorganise the code.

For example I have three named beans that repeat this code about Collars:

```
@Named(value = "dogController")
@ViewScoped
public class DogController implements Serializable {

    private Dog dog;  // Class Dog has a List<Collar>
    private Collar collar = new Collar();  // to be used in an XHTML form
    ....
    public addCollar(){
        //adds collar in dog
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        //removes collar from dog
    }
  }
```

So beans `CatController` and `BirdController` have also the same code. The same happens with `Photo`, all of them repeat code. So I think I am behind a pattern here.

My immediate step is to create an `interface HasCollar` for `Dog`, `Cat` and `Bird`. Then I move the repeated code into a new bean:

```
@Named(value = "collarController")
@ViewScoped
public class CollarController implements Serializable {

    private HasCollar animal;
    private Collar collar = new Collar();  // to be used from the XHTML
    ....
    public addCollar(){
        //adds collar in animal
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        //removes collar from animal
    }
  }
```

So far so good. My problem now is:

- How can I initialise `animal`? Especially because the same XHTML might use both a `Dog` and a `Cat`. Before it was fine because there was a `Collar` object per each type. If I have to inject it, I have no idea how. (The problem seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779480/regarding-communication-between-managed-bean-in-jsf), but it differs slightly).
- Normally I would extend the named beans from `CollarController` and have all the functionallity reused, but this is not possible since the named beans already inherit from another class.

So, **how can I refactor this situation to have as less repeated code as possible?**

(Please, let me know if more information is needed)

Comment: _"How can I initialise animal" _How would you do this in plain java? _"Normally I would extend the named beans from CollarController"_ Don't... Would you do the same in plain java?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the relationship between `Dog` and `Collar`:  a `Dog` has-a `Collar`.

In other words, `addCollar()` and `removeCollar()` are actions of a `Dog`, so those methods belong inside `Dog`:

```
 public class Dog {
    public addCollar(){
        //adds collar
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        //removes collar
    }
}
```

Same for the `Cat`, `Bird`, etc.  **The code is still duplicated at this point.**

Then a controller can simply delegate:

```
@Named(value = "dogController")
@ViewScoped
public class DogController implements Serializable {
    private Dog dog;  // Class Dog has a List<Collar>
    private Collar collar = new Collar();  // to be used in an XHTML form

    public addCollar(){
        //adds collar in dog
        dog.addCollar();
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        //removes collar from dog
        dog.removeCollar();
    }
}
```

Same for the `Cat`, `Bird`, etc. controllers.

Now the common code can be placed in a single class such as:

```
public class CollarHandler {
    private List<Collar> collars;
    public addCollar(){
        //adds collar
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        // remove a collar;
    }
}
```

And `Dog`'s constructor takes a `CollarHandler`, and its methods delegate to the handler:

```
public class Dog {
    private CollarHandler collarHandler;
    public Dog(CollarHandler collarHandler) {this.collarHandler = collarHandler; }

    public addCollar(){
        collarHandler.addCollar();
    }
    public removeCollar(){
        collarHandler.removeCollar();
    }
}
```

Same for the `Cat`, `Bird`, etc.

There is no common interface nor inheritance.  Each controller is still independent, but behavior can be shared.

Comment: Mmm... but this looks similar to what I currently have, except that the actual "add" is made in the Handler. But still the code is not shorter, but larger. It is a problem I have sometimes with OOP: It takes less effort to do the actual "addCollar" inside dog than calling a "CollarHandler.addCollar()" + doing the actual "addCollar" in the handler. If this is all about making the code more maintaneable I am not sure one solution is better than the other (Note I am not saying your answer is incorrect, I am just exposing some of my concerns)

Comment: The duplicate code was extracted from multiple classes and moved to a common class, with the existing methods simply delegating to the common class.  How is the code larger?

Comment: Because now we have 1 line (call add) + 1 line (call remove) in each class + a full new class with 2 methods (1 for actual add, 1 for actual remove). Before there was only 1 line (actual add) + 1 line (actual remove) per class and no new class

Comment: I was assuming the details of `addCollar()` and `removeCollar()` were non-trivial.  If those methods simply add/remove elements to a list then there's not much value to what I suggested.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I was looking for a patern whose outcome was as good as having the classes extending from another, so the code is not duplicated at all.